# How to find weekending on friday's from a data frame on a particular column using R

Tags: r

I want to find the week ending Fridays from the dates available in `DT_SK` column, say if may2014 ends on 31st which is a Saturday,  I would like to get the data for week that ends of 6th June 2014 which is a Friday.

```
Data1[,c("p_num","DT_SK", "Tr")]
```

the data looks like

```
P_num     DT_SK   Tr
00915   20130920 1.124
1790050 20140110 1.053
1798001 20131025 1.276
2331001 20140314 1.072
233300  20140124 1.106
233302  20140124 1.106
233305  20140124 1.106
```

The code is something like this, is there a better way to pull the data

```
lDTSK = as.data.frame(list("Ori" = levels(factor(data1$DT_SK))))
lDTSK$New = "0" 
for (i in 1:nrow(lDTSK)){
    #i=1
    strWeekDay = as.character(weekdays(as.Date(paste(
        substr(lDTSK$Ori[i],1,4),
        substr(lDTSK$Ori[i],5,6),
        substr(lDTSK$Ori[i],7,8)
    ,sep="-"))))
    if (strWeekDay !="Friday") {
        lDTSK$New[i] = as.character(lDTSK$Ori[i+1])
    }else{
        lDTSK$New[i] = as.character(lDTSK$Ori[i])
    }
}
lDTSK$New = paste("TRx_",lDTSK$New,sep="")
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/489704). We don't know what column `Dt_SK` looks like. Also, your question is unclear - what do you mean by "the week ending on Fridays"?

Comment: Do you know how to (in general) select rows of a data.frame satisfying a condition?

Comment: There is a function `nextfri` in the zoo package's zoo-quickref vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf that may help.

Comment: every week ends on Friday. Do you want the last or first complete week lying in a special month?

Comment: Hi nnn, i would like to find the last-day of each week (that is Friday).